# positionning a css button

Tags: css, html

I want  to make a button to appear in the next line . But i tried to use the attributes "position" and "line-height" of the button but nothing is changed .i want it in the center of the next line under the input text of tne name
[image: the button i want to move it to the next line]

this is my code :

css file :

```
#popup {
font-family: 'Orbitron', serif;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: 700;     
text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #fff;

color: #222;

position: absolute;   
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;

background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);

display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;          

-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;}

   #popup h1 {
font-weight: 400;
   }

   #popup-box {
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
background: #ccc url(../images/popup_bg.jpg);

border-radius: 10px;

position: relative;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #333;

display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;

-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;}

    #popup-box small {
font-size: .6em; }


   #popup.hide {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
visibility: hidden;     
    }
     #popup.hide #popup-box{
margin-top: -800px;}


  #popup-box a.button {
background: white;
border-radius: 10px;
display: block;
font-size: 30px;
margin: 230px auto 0;
padding: 10px;
width: 50px;
border: 3px solid #006438;
color:#006438;
text-decoration:none;
cursor:pointer;}
```

html file :

```
<section id="popup">
    <div id="popup-bg">
    </div>
 <div id="popup-box">   
 <p><a id="gamelogin1" class="button"   href="">choose Name</a></p>
 <p><a id="gamelogin2" class="button"   href="">New Name</a></p>
 </div>
</section>

<section id="popupName" class="hide">
   <div id="popup-bg">
    </div>
 <div id="popup-box">   
 <label for="firstName">Your Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" size="20" maxlength="40"  id="firstName" />

 **<p><a id="validatelogin" class="button"  href="">Validate</a></p> //this is the //button i want to change**
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a break line (`<br>`) after your input field:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" size="20" maxlength="40"  id="firstName" /><br>
```

Some would argue that the `<br>` tag should self-close: `<br />`, but this isn't necessary.

To make it center, use this CSS:

```
#validatelogin {
    width:100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Set width to the proper width of the button; it must be fixed in order for `margin: 0 auto;` to work.

Comment: Nope, but I've used it with forms like this many times in the past. Granted, there may be a style somewhere that overrides this behavior, but that's unlikely.

Comment: the validate button is moved to the right and down in the popup-Name (the dark one )but i want it in the white popup (popup-box)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but maybe you can use it before your button

```
<div class="both"></div>
```

In css

```
.both{
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need 
`input[type=text]
{
display:block;
}`
and 
`#validatelogin{
display:block;
}`
in your CSS. That Would solve your Issue